# Joomla user info submission

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

I am submitting a form for users who are already logged in in the front end, but how can I distinguish between submittions? I want to have a 'user' field in my DB that shows who submitted each entry, but how do I find out which user is logged in and submit that info with the form?

Also, I tried looking for some development tutorials for 1.7, but can't find anything decent, any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

You would then need to INSERT or SET this name in your database.

Comment: From there you would need to pull the information from the database.  Most of the front-end will only ever see the id or the username.

Comment: You can then call out the Real Name

Comment: Hi, I tried the $user = JFactory::getUser(); but i get teh result "JUser" only, I'm not as advanced in programming, can I get some more details?

Comment: `$user = JFactory::getUser();` is the object you need to do `$user->name` get the real name from the object.  Both lines are needed so that you can properly load the information.